# Why am I getting opposite?

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

The question asks to prove that $ab+bc+ca \geq\frac1 3$ given that $a,b,c $are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$

I solved in this way.

$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$

$\implies1=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)......(i)$

Also,$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$

$\implies a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca......(ii)$

From these two equations we get

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=1-3(ab+bc+ca)$

By AM-GM inequality

$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq 3abc$

$\implies a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\geq 0$

$\implies 1-3(ab+bc+ca)\geq 0$

$\implies (ab+bc+ca)\leq \frac 1 3$

As you can see I proved an opposite thing. So please point out my mistake ; if any. You are thanked in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot comment:

Try the inequality with $a= 1-2\epsilon$, $b=\epsilon$ and $c=\epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ a tiny but positive real.

Comment: I asked for proof-verification

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha I gave you a hint

Comment: How can you assume b=c

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha IF you took my advice and tried the inequality with these values, you'd see that the question is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought that the question is incorrect.